# How to show time and value in Y-axis in bar chart of crystal report window application

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i am working on crystal report. crystal report show date of selected month on X-Axis and Time on y-Axis.. but i have problem with my y-axis time.. Not show Correct time. its show 00:00:00 not time on date wise.

[Here is image of my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhjbV.jpg)

**What I have tried:**

i have tried this formula

**TimeValue({Attendance.TOTALTIME})**

here totaltime is time format 00:00:00

thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting correct time when placed in report?

Comment: Yeah i am getting correct time in report you can see in this report..

Comment: [PIC ](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QhjbV.jpg)

Comment: if it displays in report then it should display in graph aswell.... check whether you used same formula in graph and one more option would be where are you placing the graph... place the formula in that section and check values

Comment: i am placing the graph in Footer section and ** On change of ** Enter The value column Totaltime without any formula .. in show value..  its show count of Attedance.Totaltime.

Comment: one more thing i am putting this graph in Crystal Report Footer Section. but this not shown time in y-axis..   thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt whether you will be able to achive this because when you are taking time in `show value` then it is taking it as count...May be my knowledge is not sufficient.. will check for experts to comments on this chart....Becasue as soon as you take time in value part it is converted back to interger value as `count` or `distinct count`..

Comment: yeah you are right.. show value treat time as int.. how i can fix it.

Comment: thanks #Siva i did it... one thing more .. my y-axis not show the time line how i can show time on y-axis

Comment: Great... can you share how are you able to do it?... can you post the image